# Cuda CMake 3.10 CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake, cuda

I have a visual c++ project which creates a dll. 
For this project I have a working CMakeLists.txt.

Now I created two cuda source files which complete the project and 
with visual studio the build works fine. 
I want to add the matching commands to my cmake file.
Can anyone tell me the basic commands I need to add?

I try to build a dll library where i use .cu and .cpp files....
The important part of my cmake file looks like:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Set Cuda properties
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
enable_language(CUDA)
set(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
set(CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS OFF)
if (CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P MATCHES 8)
  set(CUDA_64_BIT_DEVICE_CODE_DEFAULT ON)
endif()
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50;-rdc=true;-use_fast_math")

message(STATUS "CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS: ${CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS}")
message(STATUS "CUDA_HOST_COMPILER: ${CUDA_HOST_COMPILER}")
message(STATUS "CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS: ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}")

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create shared library project
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
add_library(${LIB_NAME} SHARED ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES} ${CUDA_SOURCES})
set(CUDA_LIBRARIES "cudadevrt.lib;cudart.lib")
target_link_libraries(${LIB_NAME} ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})
```

But it doesn't compile the cuda files with the right flags.
Also in visual studio the preprocessor definitions are also in the cuda part of the properties....any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake: how to add cuda to existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273760/cmake-how-to-add-cuda-to-existing-project)

Comment: @halfelf: The [only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18298504/3440745) for a referenced question describes usage of `find_package(CUDA)`. Now CUDA is supported by CMake as a **language** (same as `C`, `CXX` or `Fortran`), so receipt is changed. Until referenced question will obtain an answer in "new" CMake, I would prefer to not make it as a duplicate. Unfortunately, I don't know CUDA very much, so cannot prepare that answer.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the tip. I've tried `enable_language(CUDA)` in my project. However, I still suggest using `find_package(CUDA)` series functions/variables, since it seems difficult to find any document about how to link/include other cuda libraries/headers like npp, curand etc.

Comment: Nvidia developer blog has a good explanation of doing this with CMake 3.8+: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/building-cuda-applications-cmake/

Comment: @halfelf what do you mean by "cuda libraries/header", most of the libraries that Nvidia produces are actually C or C++ libraries which call CUDA kernels, so you just link/include them like any other library. Here is how we do it for cuBLAS and cuSPARSE in a library I'm developing: https://github.com/ginkgo-project/ginkgo/blob/develop/gpu/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Concretely, for NPP which you mentioned, I don't see anything in the linking process which wouldn't be handled by CMake automatically: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/npp/index.html

Comment: @GoranFlegar Thanks for the example and devblog. I mean when  using `find_package(CUDA)`, first I don't need  `CMAKE_CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` for headers, and I also don't need `find_library()` for each cuda lib, for they have been set as `CUDA_xxx_LIBRARY` variables. The new feature feels a bit more complex than the old `find_package(cuda)` to me, or maybe I miss sth?

Comment: @halfelf You don't need CMAKE_CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES if you are building a `.cu` file, only if you call CUDA runtime API from `.c`/`.cpp` file. For the libraries, that's true, they don't have them predefined, but you can always make a little wrapper script for those, and include it in all of your projects.

Comment: There's also this downside of using FindCUDA: "In previous versions of CMake, building CUDA code required commands such as cuda_add_library. Unfortunately, these commands are unable to participate in usage requirements, and therefore would fail to use propagated compiler flags or definitions." (from the devblog I linked above).

Comment: Do i set the nvcc flags in a wrong way....the project setup try do compile always with compute_20,sm_20?

Comment: @Dominik did you use the depricated `findCUDA` package or the built-in support? `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS` is the variable used by `findCUDA`, the built-in CUDA support uses `CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS` instead. Yes, having two options is super confusing, so you have to be careful what you're doing.

Answer (score 10):

I'll try to answer this question using the discussion from the comments and add some extra information.

First of all, there are two ways to enable CUDA support in CMake. One is the old [`FindCUDA` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDA.html), and the other is the new built-in CUDA language support added in CMake 3.8, and explained [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/building-cuda-applications-cmake/).
You can choose one or the other (but you'll probably want to use the built-in support for new projects), but then you have to stick with your choice.

To use built-in support you either add it to the `project(...)` statement or use:

```
enable_language(CUDA);
```

To use the old `FindCUDA` package, you would use:

```
find_package(CUDA);
```

Note that the two options use **completely different variables** for setup. To see what variables are supported by `FindCUDA` see [this page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCUDA.html), and for built-in CUDA support see [this](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html#variables-for-languages) (don't forget that the `<LANG>` placeholder can be replaced by any language, which means that `CUDA` is also one of the available substitutions).

E.g. with `FindCUDA` you would use `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS` to set the compiler flags manually, and with built-in language support you would use `CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS` for the same purpose. As a rule of thumb: if the variable starts with `CUDA_` it is a part of the `FindCUDA` package, and if it starts with `CMAKE_`, then it is part of built-in support.

Comment: Somehow, for my project that uses `cuda_gl_interop.h` and `cuda_runtime_api`, simply adding `project(... CUDA)` results in linker error, complaining ` undefined reference to `cudaSetDevice'` etc. So I resort to `find_paclage(CUDA)` and `cuda_add_executable` and it links fine.