# How can I build CUDA programs with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

I have one of the simplest CUDA sample code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

__global__ void gpuAdd( int *d_a, int * d_b, int *d_c){
    *d_c = *d_a+*d_b;
}

int main(void){
    int h_a, h_b, h_c;
    int *d_a, *d_b, *d_c;

    h_a=1;
    h_b=4;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_a, sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_b, sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_c, sizeof(int));

   cudaMemcpy(d_a, &h_a, sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   cudaMemcpy(d_b, &h_b, sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

   gpuAdd<< <1,1>> >(d_a,d_b,d_c);
   cudaMemcpy(&h_c, d_c, sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
   printf("Result %d + %d = %d\n",h_a,h_b,h_c);

   cudaFree(d_a);
   cudaFree(d_b);
   cudaFree(d_c);
   
}
```

I can build this by doing

```
nvcc adition1.cu -o addition1.out
```

No problem there.

I want to build the program but not through this line in the command line but with cmake, in other words, making a build directory, cd to there , doing `cmake ..` and the `make`

What should I write in my `CMakeLists.txt` file in order to build CUDA code (along with host code)?

Comment: Have you tried to **search**? There are pretty much descriptions about using CUDA with CMake. E.g. see that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767485/cuda-cmake-3-10-cmakelists-txt/49836033

Comment: `enable_language(CUDA)` https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/enable_language.html

Comment: I checked the linked answer and does not provide a *clear* answer, although it gives hints. I tried Travis Gockel in my ubuntu environment and it worked. Now, trying it in my windows environment it does not so I am trying the alternative `find_package(CUDA)` which finds CUDA but still does not finish correctly. So the question is not answered (for windows at least) yet

Comment: @TravisGockel Thanks! That worked well for my ubuntu environment that I use for work. It didn't for windows but I am doing the windows one just for fun.